# Delete data from API placeholder JSON in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to delete the clicked td using angular but it doesn't work, doesn't return anything, it just gets the data.

Here is `component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  dataArray;
  id;
  constructor( private http:HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').subscribe(
      data =>{
        this.dataArray = data
      }
    )
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.delete
  }
  delete () {
    this.http.delete('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}')
            .subscribe(() => this.id = 'Delete successful');
            console.log(this.dataArray)
  }

}
```

Here is my table:

```
 <div class="table-list">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Title</th>
                  <th scope="col">Operations</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of dataArray;" index as i>
                  <td>{{item.title}}</td>
                  <td> <i class="fal fa-check-circle px-2"></i> <i class="fal fa-edit px-2"></i> <button><i class="fal fa-trash-alt" (click)="delete()"></i></button> </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a parameter to your delete function :

```
delete (id: number) {
this.http.delete('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
        .subscribe(() => this.id = 'Delete successful');
        console.log(this.dataArray)
```

}

On your html add `(click)="delete(item.id)`

Then to remove the data from the array you have to run :

```
this.array = this.array.filter((d) => d.id !== id));
```